# Modulus to limit latitude and longitude values

Tags: c, math, floating-point, intervals, modulo

I have doubles that represent latitudes and longitudes.
I can easily limit longitudes to **(-180.0, 180.0]** with the following function.

```
double limitLon(double lon)
{
  return fmod(lon - 180.0, 360.0) + 180.0;
}
```

This works because one end is exclusive and the other is inclusive. fmod includes 0 but not -360.0.

Can anyone think of an elegant method for latitude?
The required interval is **[-90.0, 90.0]**. A closed form solution would be best, i.e. no loop. I think fmod() is probably a non-starter because both ends are inclusive now.

**Edit:** As was pointed out, one can't go to 91 degrees latitude anyway. Technically 91 should map to 89.0. Oh boy, that changes things.

Comment: What would you expect 91 to translate to?  If you go over the pole by one degree you'd be back at 89 not -89.

Comment: Excellent point. Latitudes do not wrap since you can't really "cross" a pole. One can, however, cross the international date line.

Comment: did you mean fmod(lon + 180.0, 360.0) - 180.0; ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using the `sin` and inverse functions?

```
asin(sin((lat/180.0)*3.14159265)) * (180.0/3.14159265);
```

Comment: `asin` returns radians, `sin` expect radians.

Comment: This is certainly the right track. The trigonometry functions are inclusive on both ends.

Comment: I executed this, as written with lat set to 90, on Mac OS X 10.6.8, and it returned a value slightly over 90, (90.0000001 and a bit more), largely because the value written for π, 3.14159265, is too small. Correcting this to 3.1415926535897932384626433 resulted in 90. However, it should be noted that this expression still introduces rounding errors (with other values for lat) even with that change.

Comment: This error (90.0000001) amounts to about 11 millimetres on Planet Earth. Just sayin.

Answer (score 7):

Using trig functions `sin()/cos()` is expensive in time and introduces loss of precision.  Much better to use the `remainder()` function.  Note the result has the same sign as `x` and magnitude less than the magnitude of `y`, if able.

OP was on the right track!  The below solution is easy to adjust per the edge values of -180 and + 180.0.

```
#include <math.h>

// Reduce to (-180.0, 180.0]
double Limit_Longitude(double longitude_degrees) {
  // A good implementation of `fmod()` will introduce _no_ loss of precision.
  // -360.0 <= longitude_reduced <=- 360.0
  double longitude_reduced = fmod(longitude_degrees, 360.0);

  if (longitude_reduced > 180.0) {
    longitude_reduced -= 360.0;
  } else if (longitude_reduced <= -180.0) {
    longitude_reduced += 360.0;
  }
  return longitude_reduced;
}
```

Limiting Latitude to [-90 to +90] is trickier as a latitude of +91 degrees is  going over the North Pole but switching the longitude +/- 180 degrees.  To preserve longitude precision, adjust by 180 toward 0 degrees.

```
void Limit_Latitude_Longitude(double *latitude_degrees, double *longitude_degrees) {
  *latitude_degrees = Limit_Longitude(*latitude_degrees);
  int flip = 0;
  if (*latitude_degrees > 90.0) {
    *latitude_degrees = 180.0 - *latitude_degrees;
    flip = 1;
  } else if (*latitude_degrees < -90.0) {
    *latitude_degrees = -180.0 - *latitude_degrees;
    flip = 1;
  }
  if (flip) {
    *longitude_degrees += *longitude_degrees > 0 ? -180.0 : 180.0;
  }
  *longitude_degrees = Limit_Longitude(*longitude_degrees);
}
```

---

Minor: Although the goal is "limit longitudes to (-180.0, 180.0]", I'd expect ranges of [-180.0, 180.0), [-180.0, 180.0] to be more commonly needed.

Comment: Why don't use just `std::remainder(val, 360)` and get interval [-180.0, 180.0]?

Comment: @Andrew Good idea.  IIRC, `remainder(v, 360.0)` is a reasonable alternative.  Available since C99.  It does not inherit present rounding mode and half-way cases have a rigid  functionality - good or bad depending on goal.  With OP's goal of (-180, 180] code would need additional `if()`.

Comment: Works well. However for performance a simple while loop to bring the angle within [-360..360] for values that are not too far out is quicker.

Answer (score 5):

There is a much, much more efficient way to do this than using sin and arcsin. The most expensive operation is a single division. The observation that the required interval is closed is key.

- Divide by 360 and take the remainder. This yields a number in the interval `[0, 360)`, which is half-open, as observed.
- Fold the interval in half. If the remainder is >=180, subtract it from 360. This maps the interval `[180, 360)` to the interval `(0, 180]`. The union of this interval with the bottom half is the closed interval `[0, 180]`.
- Subtract 90 from the result. This interval is `[-90, 90]`, as desired.

This is, indeed, the exact same function as `arcsin(sin(x))`, but without the expense or any issue with numeric stability.

Comment: This doesn't work or is missing some steps. Just test 5 degrees and following the logic flow, it doesn't result in 5 degrees after the "subtract 90" step. Post the code to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Neither answer provided (D Stanley, eh9) works ... though for eh9's I might be misinterpreting something.  Try them with multiple values.

The proper answers are unfortunately expensive.  See the following from Microsoft Research: https://web.archive.org/web/20150109080324/http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/wraplatitudelongitude/.

From there, the answers are:
`latitude_new = atan(sin(latitude)/fabs(cos(latitude)))` -- note the absolute value around cos(latitude)

```
longitude_new = atan2(sin(latitude),cos(latitude))
```

Note that in C you may want to use `atan2f` (float vs double).  Also, all trig functions take radians.

Comment: I just came back to close that parenthesis missing from the source ... thanks @Makyen (and for the code display fix).

Comment: This link is dead now =(